# How can I fetch the images in order in parse using ANDROID

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I have successfully downloaded images from parse but the problem is they are not fetched in order. The images are being downloaded in a background process and I am inserting them in an arrayList to populate the listView. How can I check whether the images are inserted in the same order in the arrayList as they are in the parse backend ? What I have figured out so far is that some images have a smaller size so they are fetched quickly and inserted into the list first but that's not what I want. I want them to be in the same order. What is the possible solution ?

```
public class FetchClients extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<String> objectID = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> name              = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> address           = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> unitNumber       = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<String> city              = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> state             = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> zipCode           = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<byte[]> customerImage     = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
private ListView listView;
private ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter;
ImageView testView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customers_list);

  //  contactsAdapter =
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    loadListView(); // load data in listView


    listView.setFocusable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClientDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", name.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("address", address.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("unitNumber",unitNumber.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("city", city.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("state", state.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("zipCode", zipCode.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("customerImage", customerImage.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

public void loadListView(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Customer");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> customer, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < customer.size(); i++) {
                    objectID.add(customer.get(i).getObjectId());
                    name.add(customer.get(i).getString("accountHolder"));
                    address.add(customer.get(i).getString("streetAddress"));
                    unitNumber.add(customer.get(i).getInt("unitNumber"));
                    city.add(customer.get(i).getString("city"));
                    state.add(customer.get(i).getString("state"));
                    zipCode.add(customer.get(i).getString("zipCode"));

                    try {
                        ParseFile imageFile = (ParseFile) customer.get(i).get("customerImage");

                        imageFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                                    customerImage.add(data);
                                    //contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), name
                                            , city, customerImage)); //set custom ListAdapter

                                } else {
                                    Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
                }

            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some sorting_id from back end with image URL so you can decide where to put this image in Array.

Comment: Yes that might be a possible solution. But is any other better solution available ? Currently another solution that I implemented was to use getData() instead of get in background